Can DLRS write an aggregate result to a field on the Child Object?
Wondering whether this is possible with DLRS or if what I'm trying to do is too funky.
Let's say I have a Parent Object "Location" with a Child Object "Assessments".
Each Assessment has a "Year" and there are multiple assessments/rows per Year and a numerical "Score" per row.
What I would like to know is whether it is possible to use DLRS to calculate the average Score for each Year and post this to a field on the Assessments table.
I know I can achieve this with a Salesforce Report using subtotals as well as using summary formulas, but I would like to be able to show this in something like an Assessments list view.
I'm trying to avoid having to create a "Year" junction object between Location and Assessments just to hold this average value. I suppose I could probably use Flow but why reinvent the wheel if DLRS can do it.... hence my question.

The best resource for DLRS support is the Trailblazer discussion group

DLRS can only update the parent record using the aggregate operation on the children

Ah no worries, thank you for confirming that
